# Range Slider Only Updates Value Going Up But not Down

Tags: jquery, css, range

I'm trying to add a css class based on where my range slider is. It works going up. So if I go to 50 it adds class *new-background1* and if I go to 100 it adds *new-background2* but if after going to 50 or 100 I try to slide back down to 0, for example, it will no longer change.

```
<div id="inputslide">
<input type="range" step="50" min="0" max="100" value="0"></div>

jQuery('#inputslide input').on("change", function() {
    var placval = this.value
    if (placval == 0) {
        jQuery( ".main-content" ).addClass( "new-background" );
    } else if (placval == 50) {
        jQuery( ".main-content" ).addClass( "new-background1" );
    } else {
        jQuery( ".main-content" ).addClass( "new-background2" );
    }
});
```

Comment: You are adding a class to .main-content container..but where is main-content in your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your slider reaches the end and you move it backwards, the color will not change because you have already added class for background-color at various position. the addClass() function will not remove the class and add it back so that it can override previous rules by other classes.

See snippet below

```js
jQuery('#inputslide input').on("change", function() {
  var placval = this.value
  if (placval == 0) {
    jQuery(".main-content").addClass("new-background");
    jQuery(".main-content").removeClass("new-background1 new-background2");
  } 
  else if (placval == 50) {
    jQuery(".main-content").addClass("new-background1");
      jQuery(".main-content").removeClass("new-background new-background2");
  }
 else {
  jQuery(".main-content").addClass("new-background2");
  jQuery(".main-content").removeClass("new-background new-background1");
}
return true
});
```

```css
.new-background {
  background: red;
}

.new-background1 {
  background: blue;
}

.new-background2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
<div id="inputslide">
  <input type="range" step="50" min="0" max="100" value="0"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You! This was the issue. On occasion this will attempt to remove a class that does not exist (like if you go the end it will remove new-background but it would not have been added yet). Is that OK, it works but is that "bad coding".

Comment: Jquery and javascript add and remove class methods does not raise errors if the class does not exists. it therefore means that the developers did a really good job in writting these methods to take into take a non-existent classes at times..not a bad coding practice....